# Color does not change for different chart datasets

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart

```
XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();

XYSeries validKoordinates = new XYSeries("Not dangerous");
for (SimulationResult sr : validSR.values()) {
     validKoordinates.add(sr.getMinTTC(), sr.getMinTHW());  //x,y
}

dataset.addSeries(validKoordinates);
JFreeChart chart = chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(
            "Distribution of THW and TTC Values",
            "TTC", "THW", dataset);

//Changes background color
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255, 228, 196));
plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GRAY);

XYSeriesCollection dataset2 = new XYSeriesCollection();
XYSeries warningKoordinates = new XYSeries("Very critical");
for (SimulationResult sr : criticalSR.values()) {
    warningKoordinates.add(sr.getMinTTC(), sr.getMinTHW());  //x,y
}
dataset2.addSeries(warningKoordinates);

plot.setDataset(1, dataset2);
plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(1)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);
```

So I have two different datasets (dataset 1 and dataset 2). Each dataset contains different values. My aim is to change the color of the dataset 1 to gray and the color of the second one to red. (BUT the shape should same the SAME). At the beginning I only had one dataset with 2 XYSeries. The problem at that time was that the shape was different for each XYSeries. Now I have the opposite problem. The shape stays but the color does not change.

This is what my table looks right now:

[image: chart]

As you can see right now I cant seperate which one is very critical and whitch not.

Answer (score 1):

It is found that only one `dataSet` is required, all series should be added to the `dataSet`. And using the first parameter of `setSeriesPaint` to configure color of the series. Since the version of jfreeChart is not provide, I used 1.0.12. The code is edited for testing.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
    
    int[][] sr = new int[3][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
        sr[i][0] = i + 3;
        sr[i][1] = 2 * (i + 1) + 1;
    }
    XYSeries validKoordinates = new XYSeries("Not dangerous");
    XYSeries warningKoordinates = new XYSeries("Very critical");
    System.out.println(sr.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
        validKoordinates.add(sr[i][0], sr[i][1]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sr.length; i++) {
        warningKoordinates.add(sr[i][0]+1, sr[i][1]+1);
    }
    // Add dataset for all series
    dataset.addSeries(validKoordinates);
    dataset.addSeries(warningKoordinates);
    // Only reference one dataset
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot("Distribution of THW and TTC Values", "TTC", "THW", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, true, true, true);
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();

    plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255, 228, 196));
    // Change the index of setSeriesPaint to set color
    plot.getRendererForDataset(dataset).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GRAY);
    plot.getRendererForDataset(dataset).setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);
    
    BufferedImage objBufferedImage = chart.createBufferedImage(600, 800);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(objBufferedImage, "png", bas);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] byteArray = bas.toByteArray();
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
    File outputfile = new File("testimage.png");
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", outputfile);
}
```

The image generated by the above method
[image]